# Why wont my code go back to the main menu?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a guess the number game in VB.Net. I've got to the point where I'm asking the player if they would like to play again after they have won. When I try and send them back to the main menu if they select that they would like to play again it just exits out of the program.

```
 Sub MainMenu()
        Console.WriteLine("Main Menu")
        Console.WriteLine("1) Play Game")
        Console.WriteLine("2) Instructions")
        Console.WriteLine("3) View Score")
        Console.WriteLine("4) Exit")
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub

If UserGuess = CorrectNumber Then 
            PlayerScore = PlayerScore + 1
            Console.WriteLine("...CORRECT!!! You win!")
            Console.WriteLine("You took " & NOfGuesses & " guesses!")
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue")
            Console.ReadLine()
            Console.Clear()
            PlayAgainSub()
        End If

Sub PlayAgainSub()
        Dim PlayAgain As Char
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)")
        PlayAgain = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper
        If PlayAgain = "Y" Then
            MainMenu()
        ElseIf PlayAgain = "N" Then
            Quit()
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Option not valid!")
            REM Next line waits for 0.5 seconds so the user has time to see the error message.
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            Console.Clear()
            PlayAgainSub()
        End If
    End Sub
```

This isn't all of the code, just what I considered relevant, if you need the rest of it I will update the post.

Comment: Because that method doesn't stop execution like `Console.ReadLine`, you just output lines to the console there and there's no `ReadLine` after `If PlayAgain = "Y" Then MainMenu() ...`.

Comment: I see thanks, I'll try it now.

Comment: it should give you enough informations to fix it yourself. That's not the full code anyway, f.e. `If UserGuess = CorrectNumber` is between two methods.

Comment: @JakeMills: By prompting for and reading user input after displaying the main menu.  Where else in this application do you receive user input?  It would work like that.

Comment: Got it, it's working fine now, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

set a variable for recursion example
Dim recur As Char
then use Do .. loop while